# Error when getting key from KeyStore (java)

Tags: java, keystore

I'm facing a very weird error. This error started to happen today, it was working on Friday, and nothing changed, at least nothing I know.

I have a simple KeyStore where I store a key to encrypt some data. Just for testing a created a separate application to handle this. This is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {

       prop.load(new FileInputStream("./security/security.properties"));

       String ksFile = prop.getProperty("KSFile");
       String ksPassword = prop.getProperty("KSPassword");
       String keyAlias = prop.getProperty("KeyAlias");
       String keyPassword = prop.getProperty("KeyPassword");
       prop.getProperty("CardDataEncryptionKey");

       KeyStore ks;
       ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");

       FileInputStream fis = null;
       fis = new FileInputStream(ksFile);

       ks.load(fis, ksPassword.toCharArray());


       // For symmetric
       char[] keycharArray = keyPassword.toCharArray();
       ProtectionParameter proParam = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection( keycharArray );

       KeyStore.Entry entry = ks.getEntry( keyAlias, proParam );
       SecretKeyEntry aeskey = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) entry;         

       aeskey.getSecretKey();


       fis.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Code is very basic and just open the keystore configured in security.properties. The problem is now I'm getting an error in the following line:

```
       KeyStore.Entry entry = ks.getEntry( keyAlias, proParam );
```

I repeat this wasn't happening, just started suddenly. File is ok, paths are ok, the file is opened, but when I try to get the KeyEntry, I'm getting a NumberFormatException, really don't have a clue if what's going on. This is the error stack trace:

```
Test at localhost:62013 
    Thread [main] (Suspended (exception NumberFormatException)) 
        owns: InetAddress$Cache  (id=58)    
        owns: Object  (id=59)   
        Integer.parseInt(String, int) line: not available   
        Integer.<init>(String) line: not available  
        InetAddressCachePolicy.<clinit>() line: not available   
        InetAddress$Cache.getPolicy() line: not available   
        InetAddress$Cache.put(String, InetAddress[]) line: not available    
        InetAddress.cacheInitIfNeeded() line: not available 
        InetAddress.cacheAddresses(String, InetAddress[], boolean) line: not available  
        InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(String, InetAddress) line: not available    
        InetAddress.getLocalHost() line: not available  
        JarVerifier.getSystemEntropy() line: 783    
        JarVerifier.testSignatures(X509Certificate, CertificateFactory) line: 706   
        JarVerifier.access$400(X509Certificate, CertificateFactory) line: 34    
        JarVerifier$1.run() line: 183   
        JarVerifier$1.run() line: 149   
        AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>) line: not available [native method] 
        JarVerifier.<clinit>() line: 148    
        JceSecurity.loadPolicies(File, CryptoPermissions, CryptoPermissions) line: 316  
        JceSecurity.setupJurisdictionPolicies() line: 261   
        JceSecurity.access$000() line: 48   
        JceSecurity$1.run() line: 78    
        AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>) line: not available [native method] 
        JceSecurity.<clinit>() line: 76 
        JceSecurityManager.<clinit>() line: 65  
        CipherForKeyProtector(Cipher).<init>(CipherSpi, Provider, String) line: 252 
        CipherForKeyProtector.<init>(CipherSpi, Provider, String) line: 377 
        KeyProtector.unseal(SealedObject) line: 347 
        JceKeyStore.engineGetKey(String, char[]) line: 133  
        JceKeyStore(KeyStoreSpi).engineGetEntry(String, KeyStore$ProtectionParameter) line: not available   
        KeyStore.getEntry(String, KeyStore$ProtectionParameter) line: not available 
        Test.main(String[]) line: 39
```

Please guys, give me a light of hope!
Thank you!

Comment: Try to run it not in the debug mode or check that you have no exception breakpoint enabled. As you can see from openjdk sources InetAddressCachePolicy throws NumberFormatException internally, but catches it silently and proceed execution. For some reason your debugger decided to stop at that point

Comment: Thanks Konstantin. You're right, but the KeyStore entry is not loaded and I need that information for the application to work properly. Finally I think it was an Eclipse problem. I installed Eclipse in a new folder, create the project again and everything worked just fine as before. Very weird error :(. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Finally it was an Eclipse problem, also don't know really why it happened. I started to get this error after I changed my domain password, even though I restarted Windows twice.

Who knows!
Thanks.